# MySQL: timeline script, add users posts and my own

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing a timeline PHP script that:

1. Searches all relations between users
2. Joins the table `posts` when `relations.friend` = `posts.user`
3. Joins the table `users` when `relations.friend` = `users.id`

The script works fine, and retrieves all posts sent from user's friends.

```
SELECT relations.friend as uid, users.name, users.email, posts.id as pid, posts.text, posts.date
FROM `relations`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON relations.friend = posts.id
INNER JOIN `users` ON relations.friend = users.id
WHERE relations.user = 2
```

I need to add the user's own posts to the result, but I can't do it. My tables are something like:

**POSTS**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
id      text            user        status      date
----------------------------------------------------------
1       Post 1          1           1           01-01-2014
2       Post 2          2           1           01-02-2014
3       Post 3          3           1           01-03-2014
4       Post 4          4           1           01-03-2014
5       Post 5          5           1           01-04-2014
```

**RELATIONS**

```
--------------------------------------------
id      user            friend      status
--------------------------------------------
1       1               2           1
2       2               1           1
3       2               3           1
4       3               2           1
5       3               1           1
6       4               1           1
7       5               1           1
8       2               4           1
```

**USERS**

```
--------------------------------------------
id      name            email
--------------------------------------------
1       Adam            adam@mail.com
2       Bryan           bryan@mail.com
3       Mark            mark@mail.com
4       Yuri            yuri@mail.com
5       Andrew          andrew@mail.com
```

Any idea?

Comment: I am used to seeing the `FROM` before the `JOIN`.  Does it work as you show it?  Also, I recommend spelling out `INNER JOIN` if that is what you want (or maybe you don't want an `INNER JOIN`, and you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just UNION the results

```
SELECT relations.friend as uid, users.name, users.email, posts.id as pid, posts.text, posts.date
FROM `relations`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON relations.friend = posts.id
INNER JOIN `users` ON relations.friend = users.id
WHERE relations.user = 2

UNION

SELECT users.id as uid, users.name, users.email, posts.id as pid, posts.text, posts.date
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON posts.user = users.id
WHERE users.id = 2
```